# Stored procedure best practice? Should they check if foreign keys exist before inserting?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

When building a stored procedure that inserts into a simple link table, should it check if the FK's exist and gracefully return an error or just let SQL throw an exception?

- What is best practice?
- What is most efficient?

Just in case someone doesn't understand my question:

- `Table A`
- `Table B`
- `Table AB`

Should I do:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE Id = @A) AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE Id = @B)
BEGIN
      INSERT AB (AId,BId) VALUES (@A,  @B)
END
ELSE
   --handle gracefully, return error code or something
```

or

```
INSERT AB (AId,BId) VALUES (@A, @B)
```

and let SQL throw an exception

Thanks

Comment: If you are concerned about performance and you expect a lot of foreign key violations, have a look at [Performance impact of different error handling techniques](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/error-handling) and measure the impact yourself on your database and hardware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If the tables are under your control, there is no reason to perform an extra check.**  Just assume they are set up correctly, and let SQL handle any error.  Constantly checking that you have indeed done what you intended to do is overly defensive programming that adds unnecessary complexity to your code.

For example, you wouldn't write code like this:

```
i = 1;

if (i != 1) 
{
    print "Error: i is not 1!";
}
```

And I view this situation as similar.

**If the tables are not under your control it may be useful to handle the error gracefully.** For example, if this procedure can run on an arbitrary set of tables created by the user, or if it will be distributed to external users who are required to set up the tables in their own database, you may want to add some custom error handling.  The purpose of this would be to give the user a clearer description of what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As a basic concept, validating values before a potentially error raising code is a good thing. However, in this case, there could be (at least theoretically) a change in table a or table b between the exists checks and the insert statement, that would raise the fk violation error.

I would do something like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
  INSERT AB (AId,BId) VALUES (@A,  @B)
  SELECT NULL As ErrorMessage
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
END CATCH
```

The [`ERROR_MESSAGE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358.aspx) function returns the error that was rasied in the try block.

Then in the executing code you can simply check if the returned error message is null. If it is, you know the insert was successful. If not, you can handle this exception how ever you see fit.

Comment: Overkill unless you have actual reason to believe someone else may be changing the tables while your code runs.

Comment: You are going to have to handle the error anyway, why not keep it in the sql server? It's not more of an overkill comparing to handle the error in the client code.

Comment: Regardless of what you do, the client code will need to handle the generic case of an SQL error being raised when the procedure is called.  So handling this error specially does indeed add something extra to your code--and you would have to add extra handling of this error on the client side as well for it to make any difference.  Unless you have actual reason to think the tables might be set up incorrectly (e.g. they are outside your control) this kind of error handling is overly defensive in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Usually i will check Fk. If the Fk isn't exist, then throw a error friendly, and the insert statement will not be execute, database will not lock the table too.

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer